# 'not equals' condition when using Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, findby

How should I build my findBy method name so I can implement a where clause -

```
statusCode != 'Denied'
```

Would this be an option?

```
findByStatusCodeNotIn(List<String> statusCode);
```

What if I want to just pass a `String` instead of a `List`?

Thank You

Answer (score 80):

Have you taken a look at the [documentation about this in the `Spring Data JPA` docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)?

```
#findByStatusCodeNot(String statusCode);
```

It's akin the example in the docs like:

```
#findByLastnameNot
```

Comment: Can u help me with:      

@Query(value = "select * from test where path <@ 'a.b.c' and path <> 'a.b.c'", nativeQuery = true)
List<Test> getAllPath(@Param("pathToSearch") String pathToSearch);

Comment: i guess @Ramanuj you should open a new question for that. Also Spring JPA CRUD repos cant solve every scenario

Answer (score 23):

According to the Spring Data JPA Documentation on https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

you can achieve this by using the `Not` keyword. For instance your method would become

```
findByStatusCodeNot(String statusCode);
```

This means to achieve `statusCode != 'Denied'`, you would call the method as

```
findByStatusCodeNot('Denied');
```

Answer (score 5):

@Dovmo is right, but also keep in mind that if you are operating on `String` data, you may have to take case into account, i.e. `findByStatusCodeNot(String statusCode)` will find only records that are not `'Denied'` as is, but not for instance `'DeniEd'`. For case-insensitive searches, you can append `IgnoreCase` - `findByStatusCodeNotIgnoreCase(String statusCode)`

In general, please follow the link that @Dovmo gave.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [spring JPA repository docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) we can use the <> symbol in place of !=
so the query would be
`statusCode <> 'Denied'`
this would be helpful if you want to write a @Query instead of the inbuild repository methods.